# Calculate mass of exoplanet from transit method

Tags: exoplanet, mass, planetary-transits, light-curve

Is there any way to calculate (or at least estimate) mass of an exoplanet from transit method? I know that mass can be calculated with radial velocity method, however I would like to create program for processing Kepler light curves (without radial velocity data).

The data I have are:

- radius, mass, surface temperature and luminosity of star,
- orbital period, semi-major axis and radius of exoplanet,
- duration and depth of transit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of a single planet, you can't. The transit method is sensitive to the radius of the planet, not the mass.

For a multi-planet system, you can use variations in the timing of the transits caused by the gravitational interaction between the planets to infer the masses, for example as done in [this paper by Nesvorný & Morbidelli (2008)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/592230). These timing variations can be very significant if the planets are located close to mean-motion resonances (i.e. the ratio between the orbital periods being close to a fraction with small denominator, e.g. 1:2 or 2:3).

Answer (score 1):

Antispinwards is correct. However, for the practical purpose of *estimating* a mass, you can construct a mass-radius plot for all the exoplanets with *known* mass, use this to define a mean mass-radius relationship (which has significant scatter), and then use that relationshipto assign a mass to your planet.